# What is the Set this Topological Space refers to?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, notation

$(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a topological space with $X= \mathbf{D}^2 \setminus \{0\} $ where $\mathbf{D}^2\setminus \{0\}= \{x ∈ \mathbf{R^2}
:0 < \lVert x\rVert \le 1\}$, and $\mathcal{T}$ is the standard topology

My question is:

> What does $\mathbf{D}^2\setminus\{0\}$ refer to – is it diameter? I am not familiar with the notation.

Comment: Sorry, but that what you are given is complete nonsense.

Comment: $D^2$ refers to the closed unit disk in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I edited your question so that it makes a little more sense. $\mathbf{D}^n$ usually refers to the unit disk in $\mathbf{R}^n$. That is, 
$$ \mathbf{D}^n:=\{x\in \mathbf{R}^n: \lVert x\rVert\le 1.\}$$
If you like, 
$$ \mathbf{D}^2=\{(x,y)\in \mathbf{R}^2:\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\le 1\}.$$
As such, $\mathbf{D}^n\setminus \{0\}$ is precisely this disk with the origin removed.

Comment: thank you Antonios, I had suspected this. I had thought my lecturer may have made a typo, but your edit has cleared that up for me :)

Comment: I am trying to find a cover for X which does not contain any finite subcover. i.e. I'm trying to show that (X,T) is not compact. would the correct cover be U={(x,y)|x,y∈R,0<√(x^2+y^2)<=1}

Comment: or would it be the union of open balls centred at 0 ?